# NuGet Package Manager Console: "update-package -project ..." doesn't update all installed packages

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, package-management

I have a packages config in ProjectX as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="2.5.2" />
  <package id="Castle.Windsor" version="2.5.3" />
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.0" />
  <package id="MyCompany.Enum" version="1.1.0.11" />
  <package id="MyCompany.Common" version="1.1.0.9" />
  <package id="MyCompany.Castle.Installers" version="1.1.0.13" />
</packages>
```

When I issue the following command in the Package Manage Console:

```
update-package -project ProjectX
```

I see the following output:

```
No updates available for 'MyCompany.Castle.Installers'.
No updates available for 'CommonServiceLocator'.
No updates available for 'Castle.Windsor'.
No updates available for 'Castle.Core'.
```

I happen to know for a fact that there is a newer `MyCompany.Enum`, so why isn't it being listed in the output? I know that NuGet tries to use the lowest suitable version when you install, but in this case I want `update-package` to update it to the latest version.

I tried forcing it to update `MyCompany.Enum` with the following command:

```
update-package -project MyCompany.Services.MyService MyCompany.Enum
```

And this time got an error message:

```
Update-Package : Unable to find package 'MyCompany.Enum' in 'MyCompany.Services.MyService'.
At line:1 char:15
+ update-package <<<<  -project MyCompany.Services.ProjectX MyCompany.enum
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.UpdatePackageCommand
```

This is very strange, because `MyCompany.Enum` is listed both in the `packages.config` *and* is referenced by ProjectX in the Solution Explorer.

What could be the explanation for this? If it's a nuget bug, fine, but I expect I'm misunderstanding something about how it works. I've heard of similar weird goings-on with the `repositories.config`, but haven't been able to link any of those issues with what I'm seeing here.

Many thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
If I manually install the `MyCompany.Enum` package to ProjectX, using this command:

```
install-package -project ProjectX MyCompany.Enum
```

Then I get this output:

```
'MyCompany.Enum 1.5.0.1' already installed.
Successfully added 'MyCompany.Enum 1.5.0.1' to MyCompany.Services.ProjectX.
```

But sadly, now I have *two* instances of `MyCompany.Enum` in my `packages.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="2.5.2" />
  <package id="Castle.Windsor" version="2.5.3" />
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.0" />
  <package id="MyCompany.Enum" version="1.1.0.11" />
  <package id="MyCompany.Common" version="1.1.0.9" />
  <package id="MyCompany.Castle.Installers" version="1.1.0.13" />
  <package id="MyCompany.Enum" version="1.5.0.1" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Looks like you were in a bad state? In 1.5 we're doing some work to normalize packages.config on install so you don't end up with duplicates. Think of packages.config as a subset of what might be installed at solution level (aka packages folder). If something is listed there, but is not in the solution folder, it still not installed.

Answer (score 2):

Is your `packages\repositories.config` present and correct?

Because most people don't check the packages folder in, the file gets lost. Some of the NuGet commands look in there first, and fail. Some actions (such as installing a package in the project) will cause it to re-generate.

I had a very similar issue with updates not working, but once I added a new project, they then started working correctly.